# Cannot merge two JSON objects in PHP, the result is null

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to add a json object to other json object in PHP, I tried this and many other methods, but I cannot find the correct method

This is What I have:

```
$js_string1 = "{\"info\":[{\"thumb\":\"\",\"count\":1,\"date\":\"11/11/2016 4:05:28\",\"categories\":[null,null,null,null,null],\"sharing\":\"\",\"status\":\"private\",\"title\":\"Apple\",\"windows\":[{\"alwaysOnTop\":false,\"focused\":true,\"width\":1440,\"windowId\":825},{\"active\":false,\"audible\":false, \"height\":727,\"width\":1440,\"windowId\":825}],\"top\":26,\"type\":\"normal\",\"width\":1440}]}";

$js_string2 = "{\"thumb\":\"\",\"count\":1,\"date\":\"10/10/2010 5:07:30\",\"categories\":[null,null,null,null,null],\"sharing\":\"\",\"status\":\"private\",\"title\":\"Some Title\",\"windows\":[{\"alwaysOnTop\":false,\"focused\":true,\"width\":1024,\"windowId\":201},{\"active\":false,\"audible\":false, \"height\":500,\"width\":1024,\"windowId\":301}],\"top\":26,\"type\":\"normal\",\"width\":1024}";

$result = json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($js_string1, true),json_decode($js_string2, true)));
```

Expected result is:

```
{"info":[{"thumb":"","count":1,"date":"11/11/2016 4:05:28","categories":[null,null,null,null,null],"sharing":"","status":"private","title":"Apple","windows":[{"alwaysOnTop":false,"focused":true,"width":1440,"windowId":825},{"active":false,"audible":false, "height":727,"width":1440,"windowId":825}],"top":26,"type":"normal","width":1440}] }, {"thumb":"","count":1,"date":"10/10/2010 5:07:30","categories":[null,null,null,null,null],"sharing":"","status":"private","title":"Some Title","windows":[{"alwaysOnTop":false,"focused":true,"width":1024,"windowId":201},{"active":false,"audible":false, "height":500,"width":1024,"windowId":301}],"top":26,"type":"normal","width":1024}]} ]}
```

May somebody explain and show me how to do this correctly? because I tried many different ways and I cannot find how to do this correctly.

What I want to do is just to add $js_string2 to $js_string1 and keep same structure for $js_string1, something like:

**{"info":[ { .... }, { $js_string2 } ]}**

Comment: `$js_string1` and `$js_string2` aren't valid json string

Comment: What is the output of var_dump(array_merge(json_decode($js_string1, true),json_decode($js_string2, true))) ? If this is null, then there's a problem merging or decoding the jsons.

Comment: Yes, you are right, json_last_error() returns JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH, but what exctly is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, both JSON strings are not. They both have an additional "]}" at the end.

Executing your code raises a warning `array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array`. That should have let you to the cause.

**Edit**

`array_merge` creates a new array containing (in your case) all keys of the first and the second array. These keys are `"info"` and `"thumb"`. The result (again as JSON) will look something like `{"info": ..., "thumb": ...}`.

What you actually want is to add the second array to the info-array of the first one, i.e. do the following.

```
$result = json_decode($js_string1, true);
$result["info"][] = json_decode($js_string2, true);
```

Comment: But even if I remove additional "]}" at the end, I still cannot merge to the same structure

Comment: Yes, you cannot, but you do not need to, all you want is, from what I understand, add the second array (js_string2) to the "info" list contained in the first one(js_string1). I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Perffect. it works! i should learn how to work with arrays... you help me alot. I have accepted your answer, and I will vote up when I will have permissions to vote. thanks

Answer (score 0):

> So long as your JSON Strings are Valid (unfortunately, there they contain extra `]}` at the end of each respective thread, You could just do something like this:

```
<?php 

    $data1             = json_decode($js_string1);
    $data2             = json_decode($js_string2);
    $data1->info[]     = $data2;  //<== THIS WILL SET $data2 INTO 
                                  //<== THE "info" ARRAY OF $data1
```

> Notice that your JSON Strings were stripped of some extraneous **]}** towards the End of each of the Strings... [A Quick-Test Here](https://eval.in/676810):

```
    <?php

        $js_string1 = '{
                        "info":[
                                {
                                    "thumb"         :"",
                                    "count"         :1,
                                    "date"          :"11/11/2016 4:05:28",
                                    "categories"    :[null,null,null,null,null],
                                    "sharing"       :"",
                                    "status"        :"private",
                                    "title"         :"Apple",
                                    "windows"       :[
                                                    {
                                                        "alwaysOnTop":false,
                                                        "focused":true,
                                                        "width":1440,
                                                        "windowId":825
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "active":false,
                                                        "audible":false, 
                                                        "height":727,
                                                        "width":1440,
                                                        "windowId":825
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                    "top"           :26,
                                    "type"          :"normal",
                                    "width"         :1440
                                }
                                ]
                            }'; //]}

        $js_string2 = '{
                        "thumb"         :"",
                        "count"         :1,
                        "date"          :"10/10/2010 5:07:30",
                        "categories"    :[null,null,null,null,null],
                        "sharing"       :"",
                        "status"        :"private",
                        "title"         :"Some Title",
                        "windows"       :[
                                    {
                                        "alwaysOnTop":false,
                                        "focused":true,
                                        "width":1024,
                                        "windowId":201
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "active":false,
                                        "audible":false, 
                                        "height":500,
                                        "width":1024,
                                        "windowId":301
                                    }
                                ],
                        "top"           :26,
                        "type"          :"normal",
                        "width"         :1024
                        }';     //]}


        $data1          = json_decode($js_string1);
        $data2          = json_decode($js_string2);
        $data1->info[]  = $data2;  //<== THIS WILL SET $data2 
                                   //<== INTO THE "info" ARRAY OF $data1

        var_dump($data1);
        // YIELDS::
        object(stdClass)[4]
          public 'info' => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => 
                object(stdClass)[1]
                  public 'thumb' => string '' (length=0)
                  public 'count' => int 1
                  public 'date' => string '11/11/2016 4:05:28' (length=18)
                  public 'categories' => 
                    array (size=5)
                      ...
                  public 'sharing' => string '' (length=0)
                  public 'status' => string 'private' (length=7)
                  public 'title' => string 'Apple' (length=5)
                  public 'windows' => 
                    array (size=2)
                      ...
                  public 'top' => int 26
                  public 'type' => string 'normal' (length=6)
                  public 'width' => int 1440
              1 => 
                object(stdClass)[5]
                  public 'thumb' => string '' (length=0)
                  public 'count' => int 1
                  public 'date' => string '10/10/2010 5:07:30' (length=18)
                  public 'categories' => 
                    array (size=5)
                      ...
                  public 'sharing' => string '' (length=0)
                  public 'status' => string 'private' (length=7)
                  public 'title' => string 'Some Title' (length=10)
                  public 'windows' => 
                    array (size=2)
                      ...
                  public 'top' => int 26
                  public 'type' => string 'normal' (length=6)
                  public 'width' => int 1024
```